# How do derivative masks work for finding edges in image?

Tags: filters, edge-detection, derivative

As I know, masks like follow are derivative mask,
[image]

but I don't get it why they can detect edges and which one of them can find vertical edges and which one can find harizontal edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the triplet `1,0,-1` (and similarly `2,0,-2`) is a discrete, 3-point derivative operator. It can be applied column- (left) or row-wise (right). Let us try first with a row: a flat one, `f = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`, a step-like `s = 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1` and one hat-like `0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0`. `0` here denotes black, and `1` white.

The results will be, on the $6$ central points for each:

- `f`: `0,0,0,0,0,0`
- `s`: `0,1,1,0,0,0`
- `h`: `0,1,1,-1,-1,0`

The same reasoning applies to columns. The Sobel operators are composed of a second filter in the opposite direction: `1,2,1` that smoothes the data. So the global effect: it differentiates in one direction, smoothes in the other. THe resulting value will be high or low, positive or negative, depending on the type of contour in the image.

The (close-to-)zero values are features not detected by the derivative (hopefully non-edges). High amplitude values and their signs are hopefully the strength of the edge and the grading (positive: black-to-white, negative: white-to-black).